# Десериализация объекта из файла Java

Tags: java, файлы, сериализация

Десериализую объект из файла:

```
   //Считывает из файла и преобразует данные
public class FirstSystem implements Runnable {

public FileSystem currentFileSystem;

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Работает первая система");
    //Считываем из файла1

    //Создаем массив цветов
    ArrayList<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<>();

    //Десериализация объектов из файла и помещаем их в список
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(currentFileSystem.getFile1());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ObjectInputStream oin = null;
    try {
        oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = -1;
    try {
        while ((i = fis.read())!= -1)
        {
            Flower tmp = (Flower) oin.readObject();
            flowers.add(tmp);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(flowers.size());
}
}
```

Десериализуемый класс:

```
   public class Flower implements Serializable {

private String nameFlower;
private String colorFlower;
private int lengthFlower;

public Flower()
{
    this.setNameFlower(null);
    this.setColorFlower(null);
    this.setLengthFlower(0);
}

public Flower(String name, String color, int length)
{
    this.setNameFlower(name);
    this.setColorFlower(color);
    this.setLengthFlower(length);
}

public String getNameFlower() {
    return nameFlower;
}

public void setNameFlower(String nameFlower) {
    this.nameFlower = nameFlower;
}

public String getColorFlower() {
    return colorFlower;
}

public void setColorFlower(String colorFlower) {
    this.colorFlower = colorFlower;
}

public int getLengthFlower() {
    return lengthFlower;
}

public void setLengthFlower(int lengthFlower) {
    this.lengthFlower = lengthFlower;
}

public void showFlower()
{
    System.out.println("Информация о цветке:");
    System.out.println("Название цветка:" + this.getNameFlower() + "\n" + "Цвет цветка:" + this.getColorFlower() + "\n" + "Длина цветка:" + this.getLengthFlower() + "\n");
}

}
```

Класс для сериализации:

```
     public class FileSystem {

private File file1;
private File file2;
private File file3;

public FileSystem()
{
    setFile1(new File("File1.txt"));
    setFile2(new File("File2.txt"));
    setFile3(new File("File3.txt"));
}

public synchronized File getFile1() {
    return file1;
}

public void setFile1(File file1) {
    this.file1 = file1;
}

public synchronized File getFile2() {
    return file2;
}

public void setFile2(File file2) {
    this.file2 = file2;
}

public synchronized File getFile3() {
    return file3;
}

public void setFile3(File file3) {
    this.file3 = file3;
}

public void addInformationToFile1() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Flower flower1 = new Flower("Роза","Красная",20);
    Flower flower2 = new Flower("Тюльпан","Желтый",14);
    Flower flower3 = new Flower("Роза","Белая",18);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.file1);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(flower1);
    oos.writeObject(flower2);
    oos.writeObject(flower3);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    return;
}

}
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to com.bsuir.psp.Flower
at com.bsuir.psp.FirstSystem.run(FirstSystem.java:39)
at com.bsuir.psp.Start.main(Start.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Ошибка в `while ((i = fis.read())!= -1)`, вы вычитываете из нижележащего потока байт, поэтому `ObjectInputStream` видит поврежденные данные и не работает. Проблема в том, что нормального способа узнать, есть ли в потоке еще объекты, нет (только ловить `EOFException`), поэтому я бы предложил писать в файл сразу список объектов и без цикла его читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена сериализацией сразу всего списка в файл и десереализаций всего списка из файла.

```
      import java.io.*;
      import java.util.ArrayList;

      public class Main {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,    ClassNotFoundException {

 ArrayList<Human> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 Human human = new Human("Artyom",12);
 Human human2 = new Human ("Art",17);
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp.txt");
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
 arrayList.add(human);
 arrayList.add(human2);
 oos.writeObject(arrayList);
 oos.flush();
 oos.close();

 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("temp.txt");
 ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
 ArrayList<Human> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
 arrayList2  = (ArrayList<Human>) oin.readObject();

 for(int i = 0 ; i< arrayList2.size() ;i++) {
     System.out.println("Name:" + arrayList2.get(i).getName() + "Year:" +    arrayList2.get(i).getYear());
 }
 }
 }

 class Human implements Serializable {
private String name;
private int year;

public Human(String s1, int y1)
{
    this.name = s1;
    this.year = y1;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
}
```