# Конвертирование объекта из .invoke в класс -- Java

Tags: java, файлы, файловая-система, конвертация, classloader

**---------------------------------------------Тема закрыта--------------------------------------------**

Снова здравствуйте! Эта проблема почти прямо продолжает [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476966/java-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-java-class-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Проблема заключается в том что файл уже импортировался, класс вроде как тоже, метод с аргументами запускается, и:

```
newReturnObj = runMethod.invoke(newObjClass, self, gamescreen);
```

Этот метод возвращает мне Object из этого файла (Не обращайте внимания на imrort-ты и exends, так как мне кажется они ничего не меняют, потому что файл находиться в другой папке. Не знаю):

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.RandomXS128;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.my.javabots.game.returnClass;

public class test extends returnClass {
    public test() {}

    public returnClass Run(Cell self, gameScreen gamescreen) {
        System.out.println("HELLO, IT WORKS!");

        return new returnClass(self, gamescreen);
    }
}
```

И этот объект, который возвращает этот файл не совсем то, что мне нужно было, хотя в нем есть нужные мне переменные в Debug режиме:

[image: Скриншот]

Также в Debug режиме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть я так понимаю, они существуют, вот только Java это не знает, соответственно получить к ним доступ не получается (Без Debug-а):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]):

Получается мне нужно либо конвертировать этот объект в нужный мне класс (Вот он):

```
package com.my.javabots.game;

import com.my.javabots.game.UI.gameScreen;
import com.my.javabots.game.Cell;

public class returnClass {
    Cell self;
    gameScreen gamescreen;
}
```

Либо получить доступ к переменным. Естественно если я попытаюсь сделать это по простому:

```
newReturnObj = runMethod.invoke(newObjClass, self, gamescreen);
newReturn = (returnClass) newReturnObj;
```

Я получаю ошибку:

> class returnClass cannot be cast to class com.my.javabots.game.returnClass (returnClass is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @6ef888f6; com.my.javabots.game.returnClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Но мне же как-то надо либо конвертировать этот объект, либо сделать так, чтобы Java понимала что в этом объекте есть эти переменные, как иначе -- не знаю.

***Заранее спасибо всем!***

Ps. Кажется как-будто [эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587268/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-java) тема похожа, но как я понял -- не совсем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Боже как я это не заметил... Если вдруг у кого-то будет такая проблема с внешними файлами, возможно что **JavaCompiler** не перезаписывает .class файлы То есть я менял файл, а скомпилированный **.class** файл оставался старой версии. Он был примерно такой:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.RandomXS128;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.my.javabots.game.Cell;
import com.my.javabots.game.UI.gameScreen;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test extends botsController  {
    public test() {}

    public returnClass Run(Cell self, gameScreen gamescreen) {
        System.out.println("HELLO, IT WORKS!");

        return new returnClass(self, gamescreen);
    }
}
class returnClass {
    Cell cell;
    GameScreen gamescreen;
    public returnClass(Cell cell, gameScrenn gamescreen) {
         this.cell = cell;
         this.gamescreen = gamescreen;
    }
}
```

Соответственно использовался не тот returnClass который должен был, и компилятор считал их разными классами (Что очень логично) поэтому и возникала ошибка:

> class returnClass cannot be cast to class com.my.javabots.game.returnClass (returnClass is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @6ef888f6; com.my.javabots.game.returnClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Потому что **returnClass != com.my.javabots.game.returnClass** в который я его пытался конвертировать, вручную удалив скомпилированный .class файл. И уже с новым кодом:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.RandomXS128;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.my.javabots.game.returnClass;
import com.my.javabots.game.Cell;
import com.my.javabots.game.UI.gameScreen;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test extends com.my.javabots.game.botsController  {
    public test() {}

    public returnClass Run(Cell self, gameScreen gamescreen) {
        System.out.println("HELLO, IT WORKS!");

        return new returnClass(self, gamescreen);
    }
}
```

Это даже вроде бы как начало работать! И да, обычная конвертация:

```
newReturnObj = runMethod.invoke(newObjClass, self, gamescreen);
newReturn = (returnClass) newReturnObj;
```

Тоже вроде как полностью исправно работает! Извините если я кого-то ввел в заблуждение.

**Кратко:**

Как я понял --JavaCompiler не заменяет файлы (Либо иногда лагает), их нужно удалять чтобы 100% могла компилироваться новая версия кода.
Надеюсь что оно будет работать после компиляции программы .jar

Ps. Не знаю, может случился какой-то баг, но теперь он вроде заменяет файлы.. В чём проблема была..